# What is the correct way to implement state in my app

Tags: reactjs

I am building a small app for my gym that lets members reserve one of our six tandem parking stalls (3x2 grid). I am trying to build this app only using hooks as a way to learn but cannot figure out how to implement the state (code snippets below).

Basically, I have a ParkingLot component that maps over an array of six parking space objects and renders a ParkingSpace component. When you click "Reserve" for a space, a FormContainer component is loaded that asks for name and the class being taken. I read in "Thinking in React" that state shouldn't be any information that can be derived from other places, which leads me to think that only this user input should be in my state, but where does it go and how do I access it between components? My gut tells me it should live in the ParkingLot component. Is this correct? If so, how should it be structured using hooks?

```
const parkingLot = (props) => {
  const spaces = [{id: 1, name: "Chase", classTaken: "Level 2", reserved: true, form: false},
    {id: 2, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    {id: 3, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    {id: 4, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    {id: 5, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    {id: 6, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false}];

  return spaces.map(space => {
    if (space.form === false) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ParkingSpace key={space.id} id={space.id} name={space.name} classTaken={space.classTaken} reserved={space.reserved} />
          {
            (space.reserved)
            ? <button>Check Out</button>
            : <button>Reserve</button>
          }
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      <FormContainer id={space.id}/>
    }
  });
}
```

ParkingSpace Component

```
const space = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Parking Space {props.id}</h4>
      {
        (props.reserved === false)
        ? <div>
            <p>Currently Available</p>
          </div>
        : <div>
            <p>Checked Out By: {props.name}</p>
            <p>Taking Class: {props.classTaken}</p>
          </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
};
```

Thank you in advance for the help. This is my first post on SO, so please let me know if I can clarify or format anything better.

Answer (score 0):

The `spaces` data is used to determine how the ParkingLot component renders — whether a form should display and the data describing each space. Because of this, you shouldn't (and can't) store that data on the Space component.

You should turn the entire `spaces` data into a single state on the ParkingLot component (six separate states could work as well, but that's not the best route in my opinion). You can then use this data, just as you are now, to render each Space component. To make a complex object into a state without breaking it up, you can use [`react-hooks-object-state`](https://github.com/adamdavies001/react-hooks-object-state) to allow partial object updates with hooks.

```
import useObjectState from 'react-hooks-object-state';

const ParkingLot = (props) => {
  const [spaces, setSpaces] = useObjectState({
    space1: {id: 1, name: "Chase", classTaken: "Level 2", reserved: true, form: false},
    space2: {id: 2, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    space3: {id: 3, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    space4: {id: 4, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    space5: {id: 5, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false},
    space6: {id: 6, name: "", classTaken: "", reserved: false, form: false}
  });
  ...
}
```

The issue would then be how to update the data. Without knowing what your FormContainer component looks like, you can simply pass the setter function (`setSpaces` from above) to FormContainer as a prop and call it within FormContainer when the form is submitted. Here's what an update might look like:

```
const FormContainer = (props) => {
  const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    props.setSpaces({
      space5: {id: 5, name: "John Doe", classTaken: "Level 3", reserved: true, form: false}
    });
  };
  ...
}
```

This will update space five's data in the `spaces` state in ParkingLot without affecting any other space data. I've changed `spaces` from an array to an object because `useObjectState` expects data similar to `setState` in classical components.